# RcppGSL with inline

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a difficult with the "Listing 11.20-11.21" ( Chapter 11 of Seamless R and C++ Integration with Rcpp). The code using is:

```
inctxt = '
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
'

bodytxt = '
RcppGSL::matrix<double> M = sM;
int k = M.ncol();
Rcpp::NumericVector n(k);

for (int j = 0; j < k ; j++){
RcppGSL::vector_view<double> colview = gsl_matrix_column (M,j);
n[j] = gsl_blas_dnrm2(colview);
} 
M.free();
return n;
'

foo <- cxxfunction(signature(sM="numeric"),body=bodytxt,inc=inctxt,plugin="RcppGSL")
M <- outer(sin(0:9),rep(1,10),"*") + outer(rep(1,10),cos(0:9),"*")
foo(M)
```

The function works, but when I try use the package.skeleton a message of warning appears, I think that this message isn't normal but I don't know what can I do?

```
package.skeleton("mypackage",foo)
>> standard package.skeleton from utils
Creating directories ...
Creating DESCRIPTION ...
Erro em if (!namespace) warning("From R 2.14.0 on, every package gets a NAMESPACE.",  : 
  argumento tem comprimento zero
```

anybody could give me a suggestion?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely suggest that you switch to attributes and use a `Rcpp::depends(RcppGSL)`. Something like this:

```
#include <RcppGSL.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppGSL)]]

#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>

using namespace Rcpp ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector foo(RcppGSL::matrix<double> M ){
  int k = M.ncol();
  NumericVector n(k);

  for (int j = 0; j < k ; j++){
    RcppGSL::vector_view<double> colview = gsl_matrix_column (M,j);
    n[j] = gsl_blas_dnrm2(colview);
  } 
  M.free();
  return n;
}
```

which you then can directly `sourceCpp`.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is harmless and comes from an argument `namespace=FALSE` which older version of the [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) package use to deploy when NAMESPACEs were still optional in R. As the [NEWS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/inline/index.html) shows you, this was changed a two [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) releases ago.

Similarly, the Rcpp package changed its wrapper around `package.skeleton()` to no longer use this option. We made that change right before the 0.10.6 release.  And Kevin Ushey kindly added another recent patch related to supplying user-functions which was still broken 0.10.6. So you should be able to run `Rcpp.package.skeleton("newpackage")` without supplying a function, unless you run the unreleased Rcpp version in the repository.

But these days you can also use Rcpp Attributes.  See for example these posts on the Rcpp Gallery for complete usage examples with the GSL:

- http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/gsl-colnorm-example/ -- which is the same column norm example from the book, or
- http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/gsl-for-eigenvalues/

You can source the Gallery example files directly with `sourceCpp()`.